# (Django) How do I make this signup model and signupview?

Tags: python, django, instagram

I have been trying to emulate Instagram signup which takes either one of 'phone' or 'email'. The image attached shows what requirements are

[image: this_is_what_I_am_creating]

Below are the files for my 'account' Django app that I created:

models.py

```
from django.db                      import models

class Account(models.Model):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length = 254)
    password    = models.CharField(max_length=700)
    fullname    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'accounts'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username + " " + self.fullname
```

views.py

```
import json
import bcrypt
import jwt

from django.views       import View
from django.http        import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.db.models   import Q

from .models    import Account

class SignUpView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        try:
            if Account.objects.filter(email=data['email']).exists():
                return JsonResponse({"message": "ALREADY EXIST"}, status=409)
            elif Account.objects.filter(email=data['phone']).exists():
                return JsonResponse({"message": "ALREADY EXIST"}, status=409)
            elif Account.objects.filter(username=data['username']).exists():
                return JsonResponse({"message": "ALREADY EXIST"}, status=409)

            hashed_pw = bcrypt.hashpw(data['password'].encode('utf-8'),bcrypt.gensalt()).decode()
            Account.objects.create(
                    email       = data['email'],
                    password    = hashed_pw,
                    fullname    = data['fullname'],
                    username    = data['username'],
                    phone       = data['phone'],

            )
            return JsonResponse({"message": "SUCCESS"}, status=200)

        except KeyError:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "INVALID_KEYS"}, status=400)
```

Since the user put in either phone number or email, how do I make django to distinguish between the phone and email and put it in the correct model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use validate_email to validate input is email or not at first, if not then try to validate phone style.

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email

try:
    validate_email(data['email_or_phone'])
    print('input is email')
except ValidationError:
    print('do phone validate')
```

doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#validate-email